# Parsing assembly qualified name?

Tags: .net, parsing, reflection, assemblies

I would like to parse an assembly qualified name in .NET 3.5. In particular, **the assembly itself is not available**, it's just the name. I can think of many ways of doing it *by hand* but I guess I might be missing some feature to do that in the system libraries. Any suggestion?

Comment: I am referring to .NET assemblies here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [AssemblyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.aspx) class can parse the assembly name for you, just pass in the string to its constructor. If you have an assembly qualified type name, I think you'll have to strip of the type part of the string first (ie everything up to the first comma).

Comment: Stripping the name is usually very complex. Consider even simple Tuple<int,string>: "System.Tuple`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"

Comment: AssemblyName constructor throws FileLoadException unless it's able to load the assembly

Answer (score 7):

There is a parser implementation in [Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/TypeSpec.cs) and [BNF grammar on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

From .Net 4 and on you have a new override for Type.GetType:

```
public static Type GetType(
    string typeName,
    Func<AssemblyName, Assembly> assemblyResolver,
    Func<Assembly, string, bool, Type> typeResolver,
    bool throwOnError,
    bool ignoreCase
)
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332784%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

What you need to do is in the example of the above documentation:

```
Type t2 = Type.GetType(test,
            (aName) => aName.Name == "MyAssembly" ? 
                Assembly.LoadFrom(@".\MyPath\v5.0\MyAssembly.dll") : 
                Assembly.Load(aName),
            (assem, name, ignore) => assem == null ? 
                Type.GetType(name, false, ignore) : 
                assem.GetType(name, false, ignore), true
);
```

You may replace the above lambdas with more complex functions.

Answer (score 2):

There is a class `TypeIdentifier` in [Alphaleonis.Reflection.Metadata](https://github.com/alphaleonis/Alphaleonis.Reflection.Metadata) (also available from NuGet) that can parse an assembly qualified name (as well as a full type name or simple type name), and deconstruct it and allow modifications to it.

Answer (score -3):

If assembly loaded you can use something like that:

```
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    string assemblyName = assembly.GetName().Name;
```

In the example above I used an executing assembly but you loop through your loaded assembly.

**Update:**
You always can load an assembly in a separate AppDomain get the assembly name and after you are done, unload it.
Let me know if you need a sample.

Comment: Well, precisely, I don't have the assembly at hand. I would like to parse the string representing its name.